# Populate phonegap sqllite database with JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I'm trying to populate a phonegap sqlite database with a JSON array, the web service to get the JSON is working and the data is loaded just fine but when I try insert it into my table it keeps giving me an `undefined` sql error.

Here's my code:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    //Setup database table
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Profiles');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profiles (id unique, name, email, phone)');
    //Get data
    var values;
    var base_url = "https://www.hoomz.nl/staging/index.php/api/";
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'profiles', function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            console.log('(' + item.id + ', "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '"),');
            values = values + '(' + item.id + ', "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '"),';
        });
        console.log(values);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Profiles (id, name, email, phone) VALUES' + values + ';');
    });
    console.log(values);
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Profiles (id, name, email, phone) VALUES' + values + ';');
}
```

Also gives this error:
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`.

Comment: Why do you have the last executeSql there? Looks like a mistake (but probably not THE mistake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error thrown in this case is that when SQL engine is trying to insert the values the object no longer exists.You should instead store the JSON results in a global variable and then do the SQL operations.Try the code below and see the results.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   var db = null;
   var resultJSON;
   function insertIntoDB() {
       db.transaction(function (tx){
       tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Profiles');
       tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profiles (id , name, email, phone)');
       var recursiveFunction = function(index) {
        if (index < resultJSON.length) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Profiles (id, name, email, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
               [resultJSON[index].id,resultJSON[index].name,resultJSON[index].email,resultJSON[index].phone], function (){index++; recursiveFunction(index)}, errorCB);
         }
      }
      recursiveFunction(0);
    });
   }

   function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code+":"+err.message);
   }

   function onDeviceReady() {
     db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
     var base_url = "https://www.hoomz.nl/staging/index.php/api/";
     $.getJSON(base_url + 'profiles', function(result) {
      resultJSON = result;        
      insertIntoDB();
     });
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  </script>
```

Comment: @DennisvanMeel u r wc

Comment: Should we put create db statement `db = window.openDatabase()` in onDeviceReady function? Can i put it in other place. Because i create cordova project with cli so function onDeviceReady() in other js file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your issue. You are looping over each result and appending to values. After thew loop you do your insert. But if you had 2 or more results, then the values variable will look like

```
( stuff here)(stuff here)(stuff here)
```

You probably want that insert inside the each.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a little bit wrong. you are working on iteration "for each loop" and you are inserting the value in string variable "Value" at each iteration that cause error because the insert contains 4 columns but "Value" contains the nth number of values try the below code:

```
 function populateDB(tx) {
    //Setup database table
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Profiles');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profiles (id unique, name, email, phone)');

    //Get data
    var values;
    var base_url = "https://www.hoomz.nl/staging/index.php/api/";
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'profiles', function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            console.log('(' + item.id + ', "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '"),');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Profiles (id, name, email, phone) VALUES(' + item.id + ', "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '", "' + item.id + '")');
        });
    });
}
```